# Snap.svg Load svg in order not available

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

I'm trying to get the (load in order) example to work.  Here is my code.
I load snap.js and then my code in loadsvg.js it has my plugin. Then main.js with my code calling the function.  I get a error in console that says "base.loadFilesDisplayOrdered is not a function".  So it can't find it any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
    Snap.plugin( function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {
  function addLoadedFrags( whichSVG, fragList, runWhenFinishedFunc ) { // This is called once all the loaded frags are complete
    for( var count = 0; count < fragList.length; count++ ) {
        myEl = whichSVG.append( fragList[ count ] );
    }
    runWhenFinishedFunc();
  }

  Paper.prototype.loadFilesDisplayOrdered = function( list, afterAllLoadedFunc, onEachElementLoadFunc ) {
     var image, fragLoadedCount = 0, listLength = list.length, fragList = new Array(), whichSVG = this;

      for( var count = 0; count < listLength; count++ ) {
        (function() {
          var whichEl = count,
          fileName = list[ whichEl ],
          image = Snap.load( fileName, function ( loadedFragment ) {
               fragLoadedCount++;
               onEachElementLoadFunc( loadedFragment, fileName );
               fragList[ whichEl ] = loadedFragment;
               if( fragLoadedCount >= listLength ) {
                  addLoadedFrags( whichSVG, fragList, afterAllLoadedFunc );
               }
            } );
        })();
     }
  };

});
```

Then i call it in main.js

```
  var base = Snap("#svgout");
  console.log(base);
  var myLoadList = [ "svgs/layer.svg", "svgs/cutout.svg" ];
  var myDisplayList = { "Bird.svg": "zoom", "Dreaming_tux.svg": "fade" };
  base.loadFilesDisplayOrdered( myLoadList, onAllLoaded, onEachLoaded );
```

Comment: Is it possible to put it up on a jsfiddle or somewhere, showing the code live ? There's a few possibilities like the order of the files and the plugin load, or what #svgout is etc, so it's hard to tell just from the example.

Comment: So here is fiddle... I'm pretty sure sure the loading order is fine.  I'm thinking i might have to build the library with my new plugin included maybe?  Its seems rather odd but i'm not the best programmer out there. https://jsfiddle.net/rlarge/e2ohut0o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are trying to create Snap into a div element. Snap only works on SVG elements.

Change,

```
<div id="svgout"></div>
```

to

```
<svg id="svgout"></svg>
```

And the error should go away.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2ohut0o/4/)

Comment: That is embarrassing lol.  That is what i get for over thinking it.  Thank you.